# If A has three distinct eigenvalues, does that mean that they also linearly independant?

Tags: linear-algebra

If A has three distinct eigenvalues, does that mean that their respective eigenvecotrs are linearly independant?. And diagonalizable if A is 3x3?

Answer (score 3):

Eigenvectors for distinct eigenvalues are always independent.

Thus, if you're matrix is $3×3$, it will be diagonalizable.  If $n\gt3$, it may or may not be ( depending on whether the geometric multiplicity of each eigenvalue equals its algebraic multiplicity).